# C Preprocessor Stringify difference in commandline and in-code definitions

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

A project has the ability to compile code in or not and there is a need to know which code is included and what is not. The functions are all isolated in single files and the code therein is embraced in `#ifdef UPPERCASE_FILENAME_C ...code... #endif` and to make handling it simpler we check with a bit of preprocessor "magic"

```c
#define STRINGIZE(x)  __STRINGIZE(x)
#define __STRINGIZE(x) ""#x""
#define MP_HAS(x)        (sizeof(STRINGIZE(x##_C)) == 1u )
```

If the macro in question is defined, it expands to an empty string which has a size of one (only the `\0` gets counted) and if not the whole string given gets expanded which resolves to a value `>1`.

Something to play around with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DEFINE_IT
#define FOOT_C
#endif

#define STRINGIZE(x)  __STRINGIZE(x)
#define __STRINGIZE(x) ""#x""
#define HAVE_WE(x)        (sizeof(STRINGIZE(x##_C)) )

int main(void) {

   printf("sizeof(stringized) = %zu\n", HAVE_WE(FOOT));

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So far, so good. A bit complicated, but it works.

But: if we give the definition at the commandline (to test all branches)`gcc -DFOOT_C  sizeoftest.c -o sizeoftest` the macro expands to `1`, so the string is not empty anymore and has a `sizeof` of 2 (two), the character `1` and the character `\0`.

One workaround is to set the definition given at commandline to an empty string explicitely: `gcc -DFOOT_C=""  sizeoftest.c -o sizeoftest`.

Is there a way to adapt the stringify macros to ignore that discrepancy and handle both ways to define a macro in the same way?

EDIT:
The proposed answer at [Check at runtime if macro was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491147/check-at-runtime-if-macro-was-defined) does not fit exactly, sadly, but it came close. Might be the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check at runtime if macro was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491147/check-at-runtime-if-macro-was-defined)

Comment: This all seems way too complicated.  What's wrong with `#ifdef FOOT_C ...`?

Comment: @nielsen That's an interessting approach. Thank's for the find!

Comment: @PaulSanders Yeah, a bit complicated but easier to use than a bunch of `ifdef`'s. Not much of a problem, but I thought someone here could show a more elegant way to do it. The answer linked by @nielsen for example seems promising.

Comment: I do not understand. `The functions are all isolated in single files and the code therein is embraced in #ifdef UPPERCASE_FILENAME_C` Great, so what is the point of the question? `__STRI` identifiers starting with double `_` are reserved, you can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to adapt the stringify macros to ignore that discrepancy and handle both ways to define a macro in the same way?

No. This is *pre* -processor, you can just type it out statically.

```
#ifdef FOOT_C
#define HAVE_FOOT_C  1
#else
#define HAVE_FOOT_C  0
#endif
```

Then you typically just have `#define HAVE(x) HAVE_##x`.